# How to number an array and output to screen

Tags: powershell

Semi-new to powershell and having a hard time finding what I am wanting to do.  Basically I am seeing if it is possible, or if anyone knows how to take an array and number them for user input.  Example would be if I am running a get-aduser command and it returned 3 results, can I somehow number those results for later use.  I am working on a script for our help desk that lets you search for a user based on display name, adds that to an array, then prints that in a numbered order on the screen where you can select that for more involved tasks.

Thanks and hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with a `For` loop, like this:

```
$Results = Get-ADUser -Filter "name -like '*Joe*'"
For($i = 0; $i -lt $Results.Count; $i++)
{
    "{0}. {1} {2} ({3})" -f (1+$i), $Results[$i].GivenName, $Results[$i].SN, $Results[$i].samAccountName
}
```

That would end up with something like:

```
1. Joe Dirt (JDirt)
2. Joe Pesci (JPesci)
```

...and so on. The formatting of the data you want to display is often times the hard part. If you wanted to easily reference that later you should build a hashtable to go with it so that you can easily reference it later.

```
$Results = @{}
Get-ADUser -Filter "name -like '*Joe*'" |ForEach-Object -begin {$x=0} -process 
{
    ++$x
    $Results.Add($x,$_)
    "{0}. {1} {2} ({3})" -f ($x), $_.GivenName, $_.SN, $_.samAccountName
}
```

That would display the same, but later you could reference `$Results[2]` to work with the Joe Pesci record as it was displayed on the screen.

You didn't ask for it, but I keep a function on hand to make menus like that. I build hashtables like that, then use this:

```
Function MenuMaker{
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,
        ValueFromPipeline = $true)][String[]]$Selections,
        [string]$Title = $null
        )

    $Width = if($Title){$Length = $Title.Length;$Length2 = $Selections|%{$_.length}|Sort -Descending|Select -First 1;$Length2,$Length|Sort -Descending|Select -First 1}else{$Selections|%{$_.length}|Sort -Descending|Select -First 1}
    $Buffer = if(($Width*1.5) -gt 78){[math]::floor((78-$width)/2)}else{[math]::floor($width/4)}
    if($Buffer -gt 6){$Buffer = 6}
    $MaxWidth = $Buffer*2+$Width+$($Selections.count).length+2
    $Menu = @()
    $Menu += "╔"+"═"*$maxwidth+"╗"
    if($Title){
        $Menu += "║"+" "*[Math]::Floor(($maxwidth-$title.Length)/2)+$Title+" "*[Math]::Ceiling(($maxwidth-$title.Length)/2)+"║"
        $Menu += "╟"+"─"*$maxwidth+"╢"
    }
    For($i=1;$i -le $Selections.count;$i++){
        $Item = "$(if ($Selections.count -gt 9 -and $i -lt 10){" "})$i`. "
        $Menu += "║"+" "*$Buffer+$Item+$Selections[$i-1]+" "*($MaxWidth-$Buffer-$Item.Length-$Selections[$i-1].Length)+"║"
    }
    $Menu += "╚"+"═"*$maxwidth+"╝"
    $menu
}
```

Then it's just:

```
MenuMaker -Selections ($Results.Values|ForEach("{1} {2} ({3})" -f $_.GivenName, $_.SN, $_.samAccountName) -Title "Choose a user"
```

And it spits out this:

```
╔═════════════════════════════╗
║        Choose a user        ║
╟─────────────────────────────╢
║    1. Joe Dirt (JDirt)      ║
║    2. Joe Pesci (JPesci)    ║
╚═════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is exactly what I was looking for!